# Hadoop for Operational data store

Tags: hadoop, hive, report

I am asked to build an ODS (Operational data store) in hadoop for an insurance client. In this regard, few questions

1. First of all, is it recommended to build the ODS in hadoop?
2. What are the pros and cons of buildingODS in hadoop?
3. Any best practices around this topic?

The ODS should facilitate the operational reporting needs.

Comment: This link has a very good video on using Hadoop as ODS, take a look.. https://tdwi.org/webcasts/2015/01/modernizing-the-operational-data-store-with-hadoop.aspx?tc=page0

Comment: @hadooper I did look at this but its explained at a very high level